# Heroku and ruby on rails: Deploy works, but running app fails do to usual sqlite3 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku, rubygems

I know that this problem is common, and a lot of questions here on S.O. presents the same solution, to install pg instead of sqlite3 and move sqlite3 under development group.

I already did this.

> I'm following this tutorial, the first chapter: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning

This is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

gem 'rails',      '6.0.0'
gem 'puma',       '3.12.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.1.0'
gem 'webpacker',  '4.0.7'
gem 'turbolinks', '5.2.0'
gem 'jbuilder',   '2.9.1'
gem 'bootsnap',   '1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.1'
  gem 'byebug',  '11.0.1', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '4.0.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.1.0'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',           '3.28.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '3.142.4'
  gem 'webdrivers',         '4.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '1.1.4'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I did

```
bundle install
```

Then

```
git push heroku master
```

For what I understand, this phase works well.

Specifically, I see this in the log while doing the push

```
remote:        Using pg 1.1.4
```

And no reference to sqlite of any kind

### Problem

When I open the webapp in the browser I can see

> Application error
>   An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application > owner, check your logs for details.

From the cli I see

```
Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 58154 -e production`
...
Process exited with status 1
Exiting
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError)
```

My full Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      activestorage (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      actionview (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.0)
      actionview (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      activestorage (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
    activerecord (6.0.0)
      activemodel (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
    activestorage (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.8)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.4)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (11.0.1)
    capybara (3.28.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (1.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.5)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    ffi (1.11.1)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.9.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.3.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.12.2)
    msgpack (1.3.1)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.4)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    pg (1.1.4)
    public_suffix (4.0.1)
    puma (3.12.1)
    rack (2.0.7)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.0)
      actioncable (= 6.0.0)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.0)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      actiontext (= 6.0.0)
      actionview (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      activestorage (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.6.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.3.0)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.4)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 3.0)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.1)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    web-console (4.0.1)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.1.2)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (4.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.2.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (= 1.4.4)
  byebug (= 11.0.1)
  capybara (= 3.28.0)
  jbuilder (= 2.9.1)
  listen (= 3.1.5)
  pg (= 1.1.4)
  puma (= 3.12.1)
  rails (= 6.0.0)
  sass-rails (= 5.1.0)
  selenium-webdriver (= 3.142.4)
  spring (= 2.1.0)
  spring-watcher-listen (= 2.0.1)
  sqlite3 (= 1.4.1)
  turbolinks (= 5.2.0)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (= 4.0.1)
  webdrivers (= 4.1.2)
  webpacker (= 4.0.7)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.3p62

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.2
```

### Question

What else must I do to simply deploy and run this (an hellow world app)?

### Edit 1 - My `database.yml`

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I can see here that is referring to a production db of sqlite3. I actually am not using it. there is only one action saying 'hello world'... Why it's trying to connect to the db ?!?!?!

Comment: what's your database.yml look like?

Comment: How to temporary fix this problem, if it came from my database.yml ? I am a totally newbie on Ruby on Rails world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how your production db settings uses `*default` and also references sqlite3?  That is what is causing the error.  The `*default` part loads in everything under the default settings which is this part

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
```

So you need to change the settings under `production` and remove that stuff.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
```

Make sure to push to git and the deploy to heroku so the changes take effect.

If you have migrations that need to run then you will also need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` from the console to set up the DB tables, it will look for this connection even on a "hello world" page so the DB needs to be set up for the app to work (as far as I know).